# Can this be done in PHP? Simple abc "game"

Tags: php

I need to build the following...
3 main function...

1- page with 26 boxes. Each box has a picture of an animal.

2-When a animal is clicked, load a new page that shows the animal. there are also 3 letters on the screen. User must choose the correct first letter of animal.

3- Return to the first page, but show letter in place of animal photo.

I am not asking anyone to code this, just need a general idea if this can be done. Also, what type of functions I can look up.

thank you,
Harry

Comment: Can you refine the question a bit more?  Are you looking to do this exclusively in PHP or would you have access to a MySQL or other Database?  Additional considerations like this will inform your answer - therefore it would be in your best interests to clarity.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it can be done.

Comment: Please try to formulate concrete questions to post something like this in Stack Overflow - the site is solution oriented, not discussion oriented, so a generic 'can I ...' question is not in place here.

Comment: Thanks to ChristopherW & Alexander Kuzmin . You provided the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can definitely be done. Look up cookies and the $_GET variable. (This is, assuming you can already code in some other language.)

If you can't code, then this will be a bit harder, but still definitively doable if you're willing to put down the time to learn.

http://www.codecademy.com/ has a course on PHP that I believe is rather great for beginners, you should have this application up and running in no time.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this was exactly what I needed. Thank you.